# Proof that compactness can be characterized by closed sets.

Tags: metric-spaces, proof-verification

If anybody would be willing to check to see if this proof is correct I would really appreciate it.

Prove that a metric space $(X,d)$ is compact if and only if for any family $(C_i)_{i \in I}$ of closed subsets of $X$ such that $\cap_{i \in I} C_i=\emptyset$, there exists and finite set of indices $J \subset I$ such that $\cap_{i \in J} C_i=\emptyset$.

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $X$ is compact and $(C_i)_{i \in I}$ is a family of closed subsets of $X$ such that $\cap_{i \in I} C_i=\emptyset$. 
Note that $\phi=\{X \setminus C_i :i \in I\}$ is an open cover of $X$ since $\cap_{i \in I} C_i=\emptyset$ and $C_i$ is closed for each $i \in I$. 
Since $X$ is compact $\phi$ has a finite subcover $\phi'=\{X \setminus C_i :i \in J\}$ and $\cup_{i \in J}X \setminus C_i =X$ so $\cap_{i \in J} C_i=\emptyset$.

($\Leftarrow$) Suppose that $\phi=\{U_i:i \in I\}$ is an open cover of $X$.

Note that $\psi = \{X \setminus U_i:i\in I\}$ is a family of closed sets with the property that $\cap_{i \in I} X \setminus U_i=\emptyset$ so by assumption there exists $J \subset I$ such that $\cup_{i \in J} X \setminus U_i=\emptyset$ and it follows that $\phi=\{U_i:i \in J\}$ is a finite open sub cover of $X$.

Comment: It is correct. Note that it is true for any topological space.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.